# Showing status bar in Lwuit J2ME

Tags: java-me, lwuit, statusbar, series-40

I'm using Lwuit S40 in my J2ME Application, i want to show the status bar which contains the battery/time... in the application , i tried to put this line of code in the Midlet

```
((Canvas)(javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).getCurrent())).setFullScreenMode(false);
```

It works , but 2 menus bar appear at the bottom.What should i do to solve this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use native commands when working in this mode. I don't use the S40 version myself so I have no idea what these guys did. However, LWUIT proper and Codename One have the ability to set commands to native commands.

Comment: Can i remove the bars ..even the native commands during this mode, and build a new bar with custom commands?